# Inserting Paypal payment in homepage

Tags: php, paypal, payment

is there any guide, how to insert PayPal payment in homepage? For example, there is something like "add news" feature, where for each news you must pay $3 with PayPal. I must integer payment inside homepage, and after payment process is completed, it automatically inserts data in database with 'post information. I can do everything except the middle part 'Payment on PayPal'... Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: well, I need to integer PayPal payments for example like minecraft.net integrates their 
PayPal payments.

Comment: This is very very broad. Narrow it down to something more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding PayPal integration isn't straight forward, but yes its very possible.

I would suggest finding a used and tested PHP PayPal script/class and using that, instead of coding one your self.

Your answer in general is very vague, maybe include some extra details of what type of integration you need.

You can add Buy Now buttons which link visitors to your paypal easily here: https://www.paypal.com/pdn-item, they allow for lots of customization

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "Buy Now" or "Pay Now" PayPal button on your home page. Then, you'll want to tie in PayPal's Instant Payment Notification system. This will instruct PayPal to callback your website with details about the payment.

This process can be fairly involved. The following resources will help:

- [What is PayPal IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn)
- [Tutorial instructing how to implement IPN in your website](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/)